# Issue during installation of Zabbix

Tags: mysql, centos7, zabbix

I am facing the issue during zabbix installation 5.4 version in centos 7 DB-MYSQL that when i run the command `zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix`

its output:

```
[root@Zabbix ~]# zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix
gzip: /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz: No such file or directory
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

but the file zabbix server is already in the server but not able to find:

```
[root@Zabbix ~]# yum search zabbix30-server-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * elrepo: mirror.rackspace.com
 * epel: repo.extreme-ix.org
 * extras: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * remi-php72: remirepo.reloumirrors.net
 * remi-safe: remirepo.reloumirrors.net
 * updates: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
============================================================ N/S matched: zabbix30-server-mysql =============================================================
zabbix30-server-mysql.x86_64 : Zabbix server compiled to use MySQL

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
[root@Zabbix ~]#
```

Kindly help me to get out of it as i am new in zabbix and linux platform

Comment: You have a typo in create.sql.gz path "gzip: /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz: No such file or directory"

Comment: Can you show the result of `ls /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz` ?

Answer (score 0):

In some versions the path is a different one. Search for the file to locate it and then run the command with updated path.

#find / -iname